# How to connect to mongoDB by tunnel through EC2 from my local

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh, devops, ssh-tunnel

My local IP Address is dynamic.
I have development server on EC2 and lightsail. both of these IP's are whitelisted in mongoDB server.
I want to connect to mongoDB from MongoDBCompass in my local.
I can not add my ip everytime it change.

I have ssh access to both EC2 and lightsail.
MongoDB connection URL

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@clusterX.XXXXX.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

i can appriciate any solution.

is there any way?

i dont know if i can tunnel lightsail and do port forwarding to access mongoDB from theere.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using SSM port-forwarding through your EC2 server (it's *possible* via lightsail, but more complicated).

Once you [Set up SSM on your EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-setting-up-ec2.html) and Install the `aws` client along with the [session manager plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html) on your local host, you can perform the following actions:

1. Use the [SSM Port Forwarding Session to Remote Host](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/) from session manager to forward the port from your ec2 instance to your localhost
2. Connect to mongoDB on localhost using the forwarded port

This will connect from your local machine -> your ec2 instance -> mongo.
You can see a step-by-step guide from AWS on how to set this up (they include configuring the bastion server, but you can use your pre-existing ec2 instance for that if you want) [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securely-connect-to-an-amazon-rds-or-amazon-ec2-database-instance-remotely-with-your-preferred-gui/). They use RDS as an example, but it should work equally well with MongoDB!